# Git submodule vs Git subtree vs dependency manager CocoaPods

Tags: ios, git, cocoapods, git-submodules, git-subtree

I have two apps/projects - one for customers and one for workers. Both projects have the same back-end API related code, the same business-level objects, the same custom GUI controls and some functionality. I want to replace the identical code with the shared one. For example to move this code to a separate repo.

Since both projects are under development everything (including shared code) will be changed very often. Shared code will be usually updated as a part of one of these two projects.

What is the best way to share the code between two projects if I need an easy way to frequently update it?

My ideal use case will be the following:

1. I change the customer project (customer and shared code).
2. I commit and push new changes to the customer repo and to the shared code repo.
3. I open worker project, do pull for the shared code and then update worker code if it needs to reflect shared code changes.

P.S. Qestions [Differences between git submodule and subtree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31769820/differences-between-git-submodule-and-subtree) and [GIT Nested repositories: Composer vs. SubModules vs. Subtree vs.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23550689/git-nested-repositories-composer-vs-submodules-vs-subtree-vs) have very good answers but it is still not clear what should I choose if I need an easy way to frequently update shared code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a git submodule personally, it's a very good link to a shared codebase that is itself a git repository that can be managed separately without being tracked in your other projects.

You can use `git submodule foreach git pull origin master` on both the client and worker side to pull in changes when the shared library is updated.

Comment: Would not submodules be more suitable for this case?

Comment: That's exactly what I said